# Azure Service Bus - SubscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSession() vs. SubscriptionClient.BeginAcceptMessageSession()

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

In the Azure Service Bus namespace, there is a `SubscriptionClient` type, with a method to initiate a MessageSession in this manner:-

```
MessageSession session = subscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSession(...);
```

This is the synchronous version, and it returns a MessageSession. The library also provides an asynchronous version, BeginAcceptMessageSession(). This one is tripping me up, because it invokes a callback, passing in an IAsyncResult and whatever state object you wish to pass. In my case, I am passing the SubscriptionClient instance, so that I can invoke EndAcceptMessageSession() on the SubscriptionClient. BeginAcceptMessageSession() has a return type of void.

How can I access the MessageSession that is accepted via BeginAcceptMessageSession()? All I get back in the callback's result parameter is my SubscriptionClient instance, which I need in order to terminate the BeginAcceptMessageSession() via EndAcceptMessageSession().

The MessageSession reference is nowhere to be found. The documentation is no help in this regard. Searching on Google only reveals a scant 3 pages of search results, most of which is simply the online description of the method itself from MSDN. I looked in AsyncManager.Parameters and it is also empty.

Does anyone know how BeginAcceptMessageSession() is supposed to be invoked so that I can get a reference to the MessageSession thus created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke the method like this:

1. Call the begin method with a method that accepts the `IAsyncResult` and the `SubscriptionClient`.
2. In the other method (AcceptDone in this case), call `EndAcceptMessageSession` with the `IAsyncResult` to get the `MessageSession`

What you see here is an standard implementation of the Asynchronous Programming Model.

```
    private static void Do()
    {
        SubscriptionClient client = ...
        client.BeginAcceptMessageSession(AcceptDone, client);
    }

    public static void AcceptDone(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var subscriptionClient = result.AsyncState as SubscriptionClient;
        if (subscriptionClient == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Async Subscriber got no data.");
            return;
        }

        var session = subscriptionClient.EndAcceptMessageSession(result);
        ...

        subscriptionClient.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I did not notice the return type of EndAcceptMessageSession()!. You are my hero these days. The Service Bus is awesome, but the community needs something more than just a dump of the method descriptions as documentation!

Comment: If I want to use SubscriptionClient.BeginAcceptMessageSession(), and follow that with MessageSession.BeginReceive(), is it acceptable to invoke the BeginReceive() from within AcceptDone()? It seems to me that this is the only way to have them both run asynchronously, but not run in parallel.